# Why does sbt-native-packager generate no bin directory?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Today I integrated `sbt-native-packager` into my `scala` project, mostly to generate handy execution scripts and/or packages.

Now, I added to my `build.sbt` line:

```
packageArchetype.java_application
```

and to my `plugins.sbt`

```
resolvers += "sbt-plugins" at "http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.7.0-RC2")
```

when I invoke `sbt stage` I get the `target/universal/stage` directory, but there is only `lib` there, no `bin` with scripts (which according to http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/GettingStartedApplications/MyFirstProject.html should be created).

Do I need to add something else to get `bin` directory with scripts?

Comment: I came up to this question while looking how to deploy a Lagom app. The answer for deploying a Lagom app is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858758/scala-sbt-assembly-no-main-manifest-attribute/45368662#45368662

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue was that in my project I had multiple main clases. In `build.sbt` I had:

```
Keys.mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("Rest")
```

which should be

```
Keys.mainClass in (Compile) := Some("Rest")
```

and now it works perfectly.

Comment: That's a good one, thanks.  I added the [jdom library](http://jdom.org/), which has main classes, to my project and got this mysterious breakage.  A warning from `sbt-native-packager` would be a nice touch.

Comment: I had to add `Compile` scope for `mainClass` key in order to generate bin script in `packageArchetype.java_server` project

Comment: I had this problem too; defined `mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("foo")` instead of `mainClass in (Compile) := Some("foo")`. Is this standard expected SBT behavior, or does this look like a bug in sbt-native-packager?

Comment: That's an interesting question tbh - I did not investigate this issue further after I resolved it - did you experience the same issue with the newest version of sbt-native-packager?

Comment: Works for docker packaging too

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, changing the configuration of the mainClass affects in-sbt running of the application. In order to configure your build to both run the application in sbt (e.g. during development) as well as create packages, you will need 2 mainClass definitions (in `build.sbt`):

```
mainClass in Compile := Some("MyBootKernel")

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("MyApp")
```

Where the 2 main classes are:

```
class MyBootKernel extends Bootable {
  def startup = { MyApp.main(Array()) }
  def shutdown = {}
}
```

and

```
object MyApp extends App {
    // initialize application.
}
```

The start script in the bin directory passes the app main class to akka microkernel, which must extend Bootable (which then initializes the app), while running from sbt directly doesn't need boot stuff (i.e. just the App directly).