# scala sbt assembly "no main manifest attribute"

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I use assembly plugin in sbt to assemble my project. But errors happen when run by "java -jar xx.jar" -

"no main manifest attribute".

I think it's because there are two files in my `src/main/scala/` directory and each with an object extending `Application` which means there are two main entry in the project. But I need two applications, one is the server and the other is the test client.

How to handle this `two-main-entry` problem in scala sbt. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your SBT build file, define the main class.

If you are using build.sbt, then that would be:

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.domain.Main")
```

If you are using Build.scala then you could do something like:

```
lazy val app = (project in file("app")).
  settings(assemblySettings: _*)
  settings(mainClass in assembly := Some("com.domain.Main"))
```

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph are you sure you have the sbt-assembly plugin loaded?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `-cp` instead of `-jar`

`java -cp xx.jar com.domain.AnyClassName`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue while testing out Lagom.

To deploy in Lagom you can just access the -impl project and run this:

```
./sbt "project <your-project>-impl" dist
```

This will generate a zip with the executable inside.