# compiling and running jars with scalac vs sbt?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to compile a fat jar for my Scala project that contains all of my dependencies according to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238060/how-to-run-jar-generated-by-package-possibly-with-other-jars-under-lib), so that I can use it in a Java application. I am new to Scala/Java/JVM, so please be patient. I am using IntelliJ and scala 2.12.4, however I am running my `sbt` commands from the OS X Terminal.

To start, I am able to run `sbt assembly` and get a `padsystem-assembly-0.0.1.jar` in `/target/scala-2.12/`. (I had to make an `assembly.sbt` and modify my `build.sbt` with a "Merge Strategy" to get it to work.) However when I try to run this jar with scala

```
computer: dir user$ scala target/scala-2.12/padsystem-assembly-0.0.1.jar
scala target/scala-2.12/padsystem-assembly-0.0.1.jar 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.$anonfun$tryClass$1(ScalaClassLoader.scala:45)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.$anonfun$opt$1(Exception.scala:242)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:242)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.tryClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:45)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.tryToInitializeClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.tryToInitializeClass$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:41)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.tryToInitializeClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:125)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:92)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader.run$(ScalaClassLoader.scala:91)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:125)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.run$(ObjectRunner.scala:21)
    at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.run(MainGenericRunner.scala:14)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner.runAndCatch$(ObjectRunner.scala:28)
    at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runAndCatch(MainGenericRunner.scala:14)
    at scala.tools.nsc.JarRunner$.runJar(MainGenericRunner.scala:26)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:72)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:85)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

And when I try to run it with java (which is my main goal):

```
computer: dir user$ java target/scala-2.12/padsystem-assembly-0.0.1.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class target.scala-2.12.padsystem-assembly-0.0.1.jar
```

Now, before you ask, "Are you sure your code is working?", I will note that I am able to `sbt run` my code successfully, and I can also `sbt compile` and `sbt package` it successfully as well.

Interestingly, if I try to `sbt compile src/main/scala/OdinExtractor.scala` from the base directory:

```
sbt compile src/main/scala/OdinExtractor.scala
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/user/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/user/PAD_IE/project/project
[info] Loading settings from assembly.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/user/PAD_IE/project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to padsystem (in build file:/Users/user/PAD_IE/)
[info] Executing in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Mar 16, 2018 3:35:49 PM
[error] Expected ID character
[error] Not a valid command: src (similar: set)
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Expected key
[error] Not a valid key: src (similar: sources, ps, run)
[error] src/main/scala/OdinExtractor.scala
[error]  ^
```

OR if I try to `scalac src/main/scala/OdinExtractor.scala` **or** if I `cd` into the `src/main/scala` dir and try to run `sbt compile OdinExtractor.scala` I get:

```
[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/user/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/user/.sbt/1.0/plugins/"), "global-plugins")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to scala (in build file:/Users/user/PAD_IE/src/main/scala/)
[info] Executing in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/user/PAD_IE/src/main/scala/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /Users/user/PAD_IE/src/main/scala/OdinExtractor.scala:3:12: object clulab is not a member of package org
[error] import org.clulab.odin.Mention
[error]            ^
[error] /Users/user/PAD_IE/src/main/scala/OdinExtractor.scala:4:12: object clulab is not a member of package org
[error] import org.clulab.processors.Document
[error]            ^
[error] /Users/user/PAD_IE/src/main/scala/OdinExtractor.scala:5:12: object vinci is not a member of package org
[error] import org.vinci.pad.padsystem.PadSystem
[error]            ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Mar 16, 2018 3:38:06 PM
```

Why would I be able to `sbt run` my code successfully, but not be able to run the jar with scala or java, especially when all of the dependencies are included in the fat jar?

Why do I get errors with my depdencies when I do `scalac src/main/scala/OdinExtractor.scala` and `sbt compile OdinExtractor.scala`? The first I am guessing because `scalac` wants something like

`scalac -cp "all:of:the:classpath:stuff:ever" OdinExtractor.scala`.

(By the way, I can't figure out how to do this...)

Which, as I understand, is why we use `sbt` to begin with, yes? To avoid the messy classpath stuff. Which brings me to my next question: Why does `sbt compile` fail when I point it at the specific file? And why does it fail when I run it from the `src/main/scala` directory? I don't know about the first one, but my guess for the second question is that `sbt` must **always** be run from the base directory?

Back to the main goal: producing a fat jar that I can run with Java... Does anyone have any idea how I can debug this? I don't understand why the assembly jar fails, but the code still runs with `sbt run`. I originally thought the best way to debug this would be to just compile the object with `def main()`, and try to run it with both Scala and Java, but this has proven very troublesome.

In the end, I have an eerie feeling that perhaps all of this boils down to either 1) my confusion about `classpaths`, or 2) perhaps my project structure? But since my stuff runs with `sbt run`, I'm just at a total loss... Please help! Let me know if there's anything else I need to add to my post to make it more clear. Thanks!

Edit - 
Per my `build.sbt` I did include the `scala-library` jar, so that it can be parsed by Java.
I.e. `"org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % "2.12.4"`

Also, if its of any importance, my Object has a `def main` instead of `extends App`. Not sure if that matters...

Comment: Add your `assembly.sbt` to the question, it may help. When you run it with java, use `java -jar target/...` or `java -cp target/... your.main.Class`. And `sbt compile src/...` won't (isn't supposed to) work on a separate source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being with the `build.sbt`. I found the answer in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858758/scala-sbt-assembly-no-main-manifest-attribute). I had to add

```
mainClass in assembly := Some("NameOfMyMainClass")
```

into the `build.sbt`.

After that, I did

`sbt clean assembly`

and was able to run both `java -jar target/.../my-fat-jar.jar` and `scala target/.../my-fat-jar.jar`.

Shoutout to @laughedelic for pointing out that I should use `java -jar`, and for answering my question about `sbt compile src/...` :')