# How to resolve "Failed to load class" with Spark 3 on EMR for Scala object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I'm trying to build a simple Scala-based Spark application and run it in EMR, but when I run it, I get `Error: Failed to load class: com.myorganization.MyScalaObj`. My Scala file is:

```scala
package com.myorganization

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object MyScalaObj extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master(("local[*]"))
    .appName("myTestApp")
    .getOrCreate()

  val df = spark.read.csv("s3://my_bucket/foo.csv")
  df.write.parquet("s3://my_bucket/foo.parquet")
}
```

To the stock build.sbt file, I added a few lines including the Scala version, Spark library dependencies, and `mainClass` (which I found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858758/scala-sbt-assembly-no-main-manifest-attribute).

```
name := "sbtproj"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.0"
)

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("com.myorganization.MyScalaObj")
```

I build this and get a `MyScalaObj.class` which I am manually packaging into a jar with `jar cf MyScalaObj.jar MyScalaObj.class`. I copied this to my EMR cluster running Spark 3.0.0 and Scala 2.12.10.

I then tried to run my application with `spark-submit --class com.myorganization.MyScalaObj MyScalaObj.jar --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://x.x.x.x`, but it fails with `Error: Failed to load class com.myorganization.MyScalaObj.`

As this whole process is quite new to me, I'm not sure whether the error is in my sbt config (I don't know sbt at all), with the Scala object itself, something missing (eg, a manifest?), or in how I'm invoking Spark. What's the likely cause of my error here?

Comment: Have you copied your file to the hdfs or just local? Specify the file location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my problem was in how I'm building my jar file. Having not done Java for many years, I forgot that the qualified class name -- in this case, `com.myorganization.MyScalaObj` -- needs to be reflected in the directory structure. I was running `jar cf MyScalaObj.jar MyScalaObj.class`, but I should have been up two directories, running `jar cf MyScalaObj.jar com/`.

Comment: you answer is not clear. You can explain a bit more by writing clearly the complete `spark-submit` command

Comment: My `spark-submit` command is listed in the question.